# ¿Cómo ajustar imagen de fondo en etiqueta body?

Tags: html, css

Al poner la imagen de fondo no se ve completa, estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
<body background="url">
```

Answer (score 3):

Para colocar una imagen de fondo, es mejor que procedas de esta forma:

- No uses estilos *inline* es decir dentro de las mismas etiquetas
- Usa la propiedad `background-image` para indicar el recurso que irá de fondo
- Para cubrir usa la propiedad `background-size` con la opción cover
- Si por alguna razón tu imagen no alcanza el 100 por ciento del espacio visible para cubrirla puedes hacer uso de `width: 100vh;`
- Al `body` le quitas el `margin`

Quedando así:

```
body {
  background: url(url_tu_imagen); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Ejemplo completo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    img{
      width: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: url(url_tu_imagen)  ; 
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No me va el código, me aparece todo el código escrito en la página

Comment: @JorgeGuadalupeGomezPimentel lo ingresaste en etiquetas `style`?

Comment: @JorgeGuadalupeGomezPimentel revisa la edición

Comment: Si, ya lo puse con las etiquetas style y me va igual

Comment: No tendría por que @JorgeGuadalupeGomezPimentel usa esta plataforma para que compruebes que si funciona jsbin.com además copia y prueba mi último ´codigo que agregué